# Linear interpolation of pixel color between its original color and white based on square of its distance from the point x,y

Tags: assembly, x86, linear-interpolation

I need help with understanding the proper algorithm for linear interpolation in the following task:

Fade the 24 bpp .BMP image to white so that every pixel's color is linearly interpolated between its original color and white based on square of its distance form the point specified by its x and y coords. Assume that x, y lie within the image. Pixels of square distances >= dist are not faded.

I need to implement it in x86 assembly.

My thoughts about this are that I need to do the following things:

- Calulate the difference of distance between some pixel(point) with coordinates  (x,y) and  the reference one(xr,yr). To that I need to calculate dx = |xr - x|, also dy = |yr - y| then calculate dx^2 and dy^2, so in fact I don't need the absolute value of dx and dy.
- Calculate d^2 = dx^2 + dy^2
- And then calculate color of pixel using proper algorithm.

I tried to implement some algorithm but I found out that it is not correct.

Thanks for any help in advance:)

EDIT:

Here is my code for this task:

```
    section .text
    global _sunfade

; arguments
%define img     [ebp+8]
%define width   [ebp+12]
%define height  [ebp+16]
%define dist    [ebp+20]
%define xc      [ebp+24]
%define yc      [ebp+28]

; local variables
%define row_bytes   [ebp-4]
%define dx_2    [ebp-8]
%define dy_2    [ebp-12]
%define d_2     [ebp-16]
%define lvl     [ebp-20]
%define x       [ebp-24]
%define y       [ebp-28]
%define dist_2  [ebp-32]


_sunfade:
    ; stack frame
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 32

    ; save required registers
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi

    ; source image data address
    mov     esi, img

    ; calculate row size
    mov     eax, width      ; row size in pixels
    imul    eax, 3      ; row size* in bytes (3 bytes per pixel)
    add     eax, 3      ; 3 is the maximum value to fit on 2 least sign. bits
    and     eax, 0fffffffch ; zero out 2 least sign. bits, to round up to multiple of 4

    mov     row_bytes, eax  ; row size in bytes (multiple of 4, padding handled)

    ; source pixels data address
    add     esi, 54

    ; lines counter
    mov     ecx, height     ; ecx stores lines amount left


;=================================================================================================
;   ------------ Begining of the algorithm ---------------- 

_line:
    ; line pixel count - pixels left to proceed
    mov     edi, width      ; set / restet pixels to proceed
        ; counter of pixels left to procede in a line

    ; pixel index in a line - current pixel
    xor     ebx, ebx        ; reset index
        ; ebx = x
_fade:

    push    edx
    push    ebx

    xor     edx, edx

    mov     eax, ebx
    mov     ebx, 3
    div     ebx     
    mov     x, eax  ; x coordnate


    mov     eax, height
    sub     eax, ecx    ; y = height - lines amount left
    mov     y, eax      ; y coordinate


    mov     eax, xc
    sub     eax, x      ; eax = dx = xc - x
    imul    eax, eax    ; eax = dx^2 (dx * dx)
    mov     dx_2, eax   ; dx_2 = dx^2


    mov     eax, yc
    sub     eax, y      ; eax = dy = yc -y  
    imul    eax, eax    ; eax = dy^2 (dy * dy)
    mov     dy_2, eax   ; dy_2 = dy^2


    mov     eax, dist
    imul    eax, eax    ; eax = dist^2 (dist * dist)
    mov     dist_2, eax


    pop     ebx
    pop     edx

    mov     eax, dx_2
    add     eax, dy_2   ; eax = (dx^2 +dy^2) 
    mov     d_2, eax        ; d_2 = d^2 = (dx^2 +dy^2) 
    cmp     eax, dist_2     ; d^2 - dist^2
    jae     _next_pix   ; if d^2 >= dist^2 then jump to _next_pix, to not change color of this pixel

    xor     edx, edx

;=================================================================================================  
;   ---------- PIXEL OPERATIONS START ----------

    ; saving counters
    push    ecx ; counter of lines to proceed
    push    ebx ; pixel index in a line - current pixel


    mov     eax, d_2
    mov     ebx, dist_2
    div     ebx         ; eax = d^2 / dist^2

    mov     ebx, 1
    sub     ebx, eax    ; fading coeficient = 1 - (d^2 / dist^2)

        ;mov    eax, 256 
        ;imul   ebx, eax
    mov     ecx, ebx    ; ecx = fading coefficient

    pop     ebx
    ;pop        eax 

    movzx   edx, byte [esi+ebx+0]   ; getting the current color (its Blue coefficient)

    mov     eax, edx    ; eax current color
    imul    eax, ecx    ; fadded color = current collor * fading coefficient

        ;add        eax, ecx
        ;shr        eax, 1
            ;add    eax, edx 

    mov     [esi+ebx+0], al     ; saving faded color (its Blue coefficient)

;=================================================================================================

    push    ebx ; pixel index in a line - current pixel


    mov     eax, d_2
    mov     ebx, dist_2
    div     ebx         ; eax = d^2 / dist^2

    mov     ebx, 1
    sub     ebx, eax    ; fading coeficient = 1 - (d^2 / dist^2)

        ;mov        eax, 256
        ;imul   ebx, eax
    mov     ecx, ebx    ; ecx = fading coefficient

    pop     ebx

    movzx   edx, byte [esi+ebx+1]   ; getting the current color (its Green coefficient)

    mov     eax, edx    ; dx = current color
    imul    eax, ecx    ; fadded color = current collor * fading coefficient


        ;add        eax, ecx
        ;shr        eax, 1
            ;add    eax, edx 

    mov     [esi+ebx+1], al     ; saving faded color (its Green coefficient)

;=================================================================================================  

    push    ebx ;  pixel index in a line - current pixel


    mov     eax, d_2
    mov     ebx, dist_2
    div     ebx         ; eax = d^2 / dist^2

    mov     ebx, 1
    sub     ebx, eax    ; fading coeficient = 1 - (d^2 / dist^2)

        ;mov        eax, 256
        ;imul   ebx, eax    
    mov     ecx, ebx    ; ecx = fading coefficient

    pop     ebx

    movzx   edx, byte [esi+ebx+2]   ; getting the current color (its Red coefficient)

    mov     eax, edx    ; dx = current color
    imul    eax, ecx    ; fadded color = current collor * fading coefficient

        ;add        eax, ecx
        ;shr        eax, 1
            ;add    eax, edx 

    mov     [esi+ebx+2], al     ; saving faded color (its Red coefficient)

    pop     ecx

;=================================================================================================  
;   ---------- PIXEL OPERATIONS END ----------

_next_pix:
    add     ebx, 3      ; next pixel    
    dec     edi         ; decrement pixels left to proceed in a line
    jnz     _fade       ; if not 0, continue to next pixel in a line


    add     esi, row_bytes  ; advance address to next line
    dec     ecx         ; decrement lines to proceed amount
    jnz     _line       ; if not 0, continut to next line

    ; restore registers
    pop     edi
    pop     esi
    pop     ebx

    ; remove stack frame
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ; return from procedure
    ret
```

It is properly chosing the area for changing pixels color, but the color is changed, and not faded. My algorithm for fading is not correct.

Any ideas how the proper algorithm would look like?

EDIT2:
The changed part of code for one color:

```
;   ---------- PIXEL OPERATIONS START ----------

    ; saving counters
    push    ecx ; counter of lines to proceed
    push    ebx ; pixel index in a line - current pixel


    mov     eax, d_2
    mov     ebx, dist_2
    div     ebx         ; eax = d^2 / dist^2

    mov     ebx, 1
    sub     ebx, eax    ; fading coeficient = 1 - (d^2 / dist^2)

        mov     eax, 256 
        imul    ebx, eax ; ebx = fading coefficient * 256
    mov     ecx, ebx    ; ecx = fading coefficient

    pop     ebx

    movzx   edx, byte [esi+ebx+0]   ; getting the current color (its Blue coefficient)

    mov     eax, edx    ; eax current color
    imul    eax, ecx    ; fadded color = current collor * fading coefficient

        shr     eax, 8 ; faded color / 256

            add     eax, edx ; new_color = current_color + (faded color/256)

    mov     [esi+ebx+0], al     ; saving faded color (its Blue coefficient)
```

EDIT3
Once again changed part for one color:
But it does not work... While I tried to run it the program stops working.

EDIT4
It wasn't working because I deleted by an accident the pop ecx instruction...
Now it is drawing, smth like circle, but streched to the direction of right top corner and to direction of left bottom corner. And it has many lines in different colors. Well, it's not easy to describe how it looks:P

```
;   ---------- PIXEL OPERATIONS START ----------

    ; saving counters
    push    ecx ; counter of lines to proceed
    push    ebx ; pixel index in a line - current pixel


    mov     eax, d_2
    shl     eax, 8      ; eax = d_2 * 256
    mov     ebx, dist_2
    div     ebx         ; eax = (d^2 * 256 ) / dist^2

    mov     ebx, 256
    sub     ebx, eax    ; fading coeficient = 256 - [(d^2 * 256) / dist^2)]

    mov     ecx, ebx    ; ecx = fading coefficient

    pop     ebx

    movzx   edx, byte [esi+ebx+0]   ; getting the current color (its Blue coefficient)

    mov     eax, edx    ; eax current color
    imul    eax, ecx    ; fadded color = current collor * fading coefficient

        shr     eax, 8 ; faded color / 256

            add     eax, edx ; new_color = current_color + (faded color/256)

    mov     [esi+ebx+0], al     ; saving faded color (its Blue coefficient)
```

Answer (score 0):

`imul eax, ecx` multiplies the current channel value by the fading coefficient, which is (or should be?) a value between 0..255 -- which is actually a *fraction*, multiplied by 256. So the result has to be divided by 256 again to bring it back in to the valid range before being stored back. Currently, you are storing the lowest, least significant 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:)
Well I am storing only 8 bits, beacuse it's a 24 bmp bitmap, so each color R,G,B of the pixel is stored in 8 bits out of 24 bits in total, am I right?

Comment: You are right about *that* .. but the multiplication shifts the result "up" by a factor of 256. You *should* multiply by a factor between 0 and 1, but it's "times 256" so it fits into an integer register.

Comment: Ohh, yeah. That's true:)
So when I multiply it by 256, and then divide by 256 It should be in the 8 lower bits?
Take a look on the changed code.

Comment: Ah -- I think I found the source of your errors. You cannot do the division (d/dist) in regular registers -- they are all integers! Use (d*256/dist) instead. Your mul by 256 now comes after the division, which is too late to fix it.

Comment: Oww, Ok I tried to do it like that, but smth is wrong.